# Looping on Web Audio

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I have an app where I need to loop sound files. It is working fine in Safari, but in Chrome and Firefox it will play the file once and not continue to loop.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Code Example:

```
source2[source2.looping ? 'looping' : 'loop']=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just say "source2.loop = true;"?  Safari supports .loop too, iirc.  Otherwise just set both, it's harmless:

```
source2.loop = true;
source2.looping = true;
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a million! Do you know why what I had wouldn't work?